# Understanding IIS 7 log files

Tags: iis, logging

I'm trying to debug a 405 error that is occurring in an ASP.NET 4.0 website with a jQuery AJAX post, and I've got the following from an IIS log file.

`2012-07-02 15:15:37 XXX.XX.XX.XXX POST /AjaxWebMethods.aspx/TestWebMethod - 443 - XXX.XX.XX.XX 
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+5.1;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 405 0 0 218`

**My question:** what does the `405 0 0 218` at the end of the log signify? I'm assuming that the 405 portion is the client error number, but what are the 3 remaining numbers?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Take a look at the top of your log file and you'll see something like this:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2011-04-13 19:02:34
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

The `#Fields` row will tell you what each value represents. In your case, and presuming you're running with the default log settings, the values would be:

```
sc-status  sc-substatus   sc-win32status  time-taken
====================================================
405        0              0               218
```

- `sc-status` - is the major part of the HTTP status code
- `sc-substatus` - is the sub status e.g. for a `503.19` HTTP status it would be the `19` part
- `sc-win32status` - is a [Windows system error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx)
- `time-taken` - is the time taken to send the response in milliseconds

If you're getting non-zero values for `sc-win32status` you can use:

`NET HELPMSG <sc-win32status value>`

...to find out that that status code maps to.

If a field doesn't have a value in the log file then the missing value is shown as a hyphen `-`.

Comment: @MichaelMortensen yes, done that a few times in the past for the benefit of customers to highlight dodgy looking requests such as SQL injection attempts. Might be worthwhile posting that link under the OP's question for the benefit of others.