# IIS Log Format - Last Values

Tags: iis, logging, windows-error-reporting

I'm trying to understand the meaning of some IIS logs I have as we keep expiriencing a 500_Server_Error which cause it to restart.

These are the last numbers, I know some of them but not all of them, anyone expirience this before?

```
Status = 500, 
?????? = 0,
Windows error number = 64,
?????? = 0,
?????? = 901,
?????? = 12656
```

Comment: You should read [this article about IIS log file formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525807%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which should answer at least part of your question... - Also this may belong on [sf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Understanding IIS 7 log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296698/understanding-iis-7-log-files). If you are using Windows 2012/IIS8, the default W3C format for those last 6 numbers is:

- sc-status
- sc-substatus
- sc-win32-status
- sc-bytes
- cs-bytes
- time-taken

You can see this in a header at the top of the file, e.g.:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-02-12 08:00:05
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
```