# Request.getParameter java to vb.net

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, request, httprequest

I have a question about retrieving data from a client who is using java and i am using vb.net.
I am expecting a form posted to me and read the data.

My issues is when i do Request.Form("DATA") i get nothing from the client.
Now if i create a html form and post it to my url with the field "DATA" i can read everything fine. I can also loop through my form and see the field and the button if i right them out to the screen or to a text file. Code is below

```
    response.write(Request.Form("DATA"))
```

OR

```
    Dim entryName As String
    For Each entryName In Request.Form
       response.write("Entity Name: " & entryName)
    Next
```

Either method above works fine for me but not for the client. When the client hits my page i see nothing at all no buttons no fields, nothing.

I am concerned he is not posting properly to me. I spoke with the developer and he said he would retrieve the data on his end by doing something like "Request.getparameter"

I do not know java at all but from what i read it sounds like "Request.getparameter" will grab any field out of a form or querysting that has the name specified aka my "DATA" field that i am looking for.

Can anyone explain to me what request.getparameter means in java and what the equivalent code would be in vb.net?

Again i do not know java at all and have searched on this for a while but cant quite find a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'client'?

Comment: a client meaning a customer im working with. They are supposed to be posting data to me

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that in Java, [`request.getParameter("DATA")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) will look in both the query string and posted form data, while in .NET, [`Request.Form("DATA")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) only looks at posted form data.  Therefore, it seems likely that your client is sending the data in the query string, since you are not seeing it.

You have a few options.  You could use [`Request.QueryString("DATA")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) to check only the query string, or either [`Request.Item("DATA")` / `Request("DATA")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) or [`Request.Params("DATA")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx) to check both the query string and posted form data, plus cookies and server variables.  I think `Items` and `Params` may be a little different in what they return, e.g. for multiple values. They are probably the closest equivalent to the Java `request.getParameter` function.

Comment: Thanks mark, However if it was in the querystring i would assume i would see it in IIS logs, which i do not i have put in place the Request.Params("DATA") and will see what comes from that. Is there any other common way of sending information aside from forms or querytstring that i may be missing?

Comment: @squinny It looks like logging the query string [may be optional](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19920936/2278086) in IIS, but I'm not sure if it's the default.  I suppose I would usually use Fiddler to examine the request, but since you are not submitting it, that's out - not sure if there is a server-side equivalent.  [This question on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/90943) may give some ideas for how to log the incoming requests.